# Host Windows Forms (C#) Inside MFC Application (VC++,VS6.0)

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, mfc

After a bunch of reading this afternoon, and not getting any tangible results.  Is it possible to host a windows forms dialog inside of a MFC application that is still being developed using VC6.

The issue arises is that we have a large application that has never been upgraded with the new Visual Studios because VC6 always worked.  Now we need to add some of the C# functionality in it.  I am unable to do the /clr option as our project consists entirely of unmanaged C++. I did a search for "CWinFormsControl" within all our libraries/headers and didn't come up with anything.  I am unsure what to try next.

Also, forgive any ignorance as I am doing research and new to this depth of programming.

I have checked the following articles:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/676cbawx(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/97fddc35-e94d-4587-8be0-0b573185eb63/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahdd1h97(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://www.functionx.com/visualc/Lesson04.htm
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/vcgeneral/thread/c38db22e-cf61-4b47-bcc8-e6202c40d1b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CWinFormsControl requires MFC 8.0.

You can [make your managed assembly a COM server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/24/using-managed-controls-as-activex-controls.aspx) (e.g. ActiveX) and use it in MFC application like any other COM server.

Comment: Following the directions I went ahead and got a DLL built of my C# dialog.  How do I call/initialize it in C++ now?  Forgive the ignorance.

Comment: CoCreateInstance, call your form's ShowDialog method via early (#import +tlbexp) or late bing (IDispatch).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VC6 laying around to try this out, but I think it should be mostly possible; at least for a simple modal ShowDialog() scenario.

You'll create a new assembly/DLL using C++/CLI, compiled with the **/clr** flag.  This will expose an unmanaged API to your existing MFC code, using the usual `__declspec(dllexport)`.  The implementation will call into your C# code which lives it yet another assembly.

Comment: What is the best way to do this?  I'm very new to this.  Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.